# NCalc precision problems

Tags: c#, ncalc

I got some rounding problems with NCalc.
My problem is quite simple. just add 0.5 and 0.5555. 
expected result is 1.0555. This i need to round to 3 fractions. 
1.056

float and double should not cause me any precision problems at a 5 digit number. However NCalc does.

```
Expression ex = new Expression("0.5 + 0.5555");
object result = ex.Evaluate();

result  1.0554999999999999  object {double}
```

This will round down instead of up. Even if the error is 0.0000000~~~~1. 
Anyone have any ideas how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

NCalc adds those two numbers as `System.Double` values, so the result(also `System.Double`) is correct.

If NCalc does not allow to force this operation as on two `System.Decimal` values then maybe you should look for some another library.

Answer (score 1):

Force NCalc to use decimals by passing parameters with `m`:

```
 Expression ex = new Expression("[a1] + [a2]");
 ex.Parameters["a1"] = 0.5m;
 ex.Parameters["a2"] = 0.555m;
 object result = ex.Evaluate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the very best solution.. but a solution.

```
result.ToString();
```

will give me the "correct" number back. And by rounding it to 3 fractions it will yield the correct result.